# Error message at installation of Rttf2pt1 version 1.3.8 in R

Tags: r, windows, installation, import, fonts

Iam trying to import windows fonts into R/R.Stuido (both latest versions used with Windows 10). Some time ago I was successful on another Windows 10 device using this code:

```
install.packages("pkgbuild")
library(extrafont)
library(remotes)
remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")
extrafont::font_import()
```

When I tried to re-run that one on the actual device I am running into troubles with the installation of the respective Rttf2pt1 version. It seems to run into installation problems as the the error message is as follows:

```
Downloading package from url: https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/Rttf2pt1/Rttf2pt1_1.3.8.tar.gz
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'Rttf2pt1' ...
** package 'Rttf2pt1' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
  running 'src/Makefile.win' ...
echo "make ttf2pt1 in ttf2pt1/ ..."
make ttf2pt1 in ttf2pt1/ ...
(cd ttf2pt1; /c/PROGRA~1/rtools40/usr/bin/make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f Makefile CC="`"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/bin/R" CMD config CC`" CFLAGS="`"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/bin/R" CMD config CFLAGS`  -DWINDOWS -Wno-comment -Wno-format -Wno-logical-op-parentheses -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-label -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-value" ttf2pt1)
C:/Program Files/rtools40/mingw64/bin/gcc -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -DWINDOWS -Wno-comment -Wno-format -Wno-logical-op-parentheses -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-label -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-value -c ttf2pt1.c
make[1]: C:/Program: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:185: ttf2pt1.o] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile.win:16: all] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rttf2pt1'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../R/win-library/4.1/Rttf2pt1'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/.../R/win-library/4.1/Rttf2pt1'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/.../Rttf2pt1’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by copy-paste the package from my older PC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you installed the Rtools on `C:/Program Files/`.

Try to uninstall the Rtools, then reinstall it to the default installation path, `C:/rtools40`.

I hope it fixes your problem. It fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

If the newer version of the `Rttf2pt1` package is currently installed on your PC, remove it. Then follow the solution provided in this [link](https://intellipaat.com/community/13741/installing-older-version-of-r-package) to install the older version (1.3.8) from a CRAN repository. In your case, this code will solve it:

```
url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rttf2pt1/Rttf2pt1_1.3.8.tar.gz"

install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="source")
```